# Unable to click next page for web scraping

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape school data from this website http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/
[image]

Click "Cari Sekolah" button to go to the first page to scrape
[image]

I can't seem to figure out a way to click next page to load the entries from other pages. The url does not change when the next page is clicked. The HTML code for different pages looks like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="paging(2)">2</a>
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--incognito')
webdriver = "/Users/rainer/Desktop/learnpython/web/chromedriver"
driver = Chrome(executable_path=webdriver, chrome_options=option)

url="http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Cari Sekolah']"))).click()
for i in range(2,15):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='list']//a[text()='" + str(i) + "']"))).click()
        print("page number #" + str(i))
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print("No such element")
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed your code and it seems to be working correctly. The URL of the page does not change, but the schools that are displayed on the page actually change.

Take a look, I added code to print out school names:

```py
url="http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,15)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Cari Sekolah']"))).click()
for i in range(2, 15):
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='list']//a[text()='" + str(i) + "']"))).click()
        print("page number #" + str(i))

        # Print school names to make sure they change per page
        names = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul > li.list-group-item:first-child a')
        print([name.text for name in names])
        time.sleep(2) 

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

**Output:**

```
page number #2
['(69839180) KELOMPOK BERMAIN KUSUMA HATI', '(K5660869) LKP ALVY', '(20103743) SMKS PGRI 1 JAKARTA', '(20269763) TK MARDI WALUYA']
page number #3
['(69990549) KB GENERASI CERDAS', '(69953341) KB HARAPAN BUNDA', '(P2965122) PKBM TELAGO', '(69930497) SPS ANGGREK']
page number #4
['(69877674) KB WADAH KASIH', '(20567521) TK AISYIYAH BUSTANUL ATHFAL', '(30406867) TK AISYIYAH BUSTANUL ATHFAL 2', '(69734039) TK PGRI TINGGAR']
...
```

So it looks like you can still scrape the data and everything is working as expected.

Hopefully, this helps. Please let me know if the code output is different for you. Good luck.

Comment: it works when i added time.sleep (10) before it's clicked. otherwise the error message: "Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (208, 600)" pops up. Seems like it's not very stable, any idea on how to make it more robust? Sometimes the program works, sometimes it stops after 3-4 pages. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is interesting, I am not getting " Element is not clickable at point (208, 600)". 
You already have `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable())`, that should solve the issue. It is possible that the window is too small and the page number is below the visible area, it shouldn't really break things, but maybe it does. 
Can you please add `driver.maximize_window()` after `driver.get(url)`? Does it improve behavior?

Comment: Yes, I did.. seems like it works now thanks so much for the suggestion!